# Cors for GET with Postman not showing headers

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cors, postman

I have an Spring app with a config like this:

```
<mvc:cors>
    <mvc:mapping path="*" allowed-headers="*" allowed-methods="GET,PUT,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,DELETE" allowed-origins="*" allow-credentials="true" />
</mvc:cors>
```

when i do a POST i get:

```
access-control-allow-credentials →true
access-control-allow-origin →chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
```

when i do a GET i do not get these headers. PUT DELETE all give me the correct headers. Any clue why GET does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is the Origin header. The Spring MVC framework responds with access control headers when it receives a Origin header. Postman does not include a Origin header in a GET request.

Comment: thanks that explains. do you know why postman does not add the origin header with a GET?

Comment: Typically a get request does not require cors origin header. But you can add it yourself manually.